# How to create a stacked percentage bar graph from a dataframe with percentage values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have following dataframe:

```
Class     Percentage
class1    0.215854
class2    0.12871
class3    0.122787
class4    0.0680061
class5    0.0670523
class6    0.0826716
class7    0.309828
class8    0
class9    0
```

How can I create a stacked vertical bar graph where y goes from 0-100% and the percentage data is plotted? I would also like to add a legend with a color corresponding to a class.

Code I've tried:

```
df.T.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

results in error: `TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot`

```
classgraph,texts = plt.bar(df["Percentage"],height=5) #added texts for later legend
```

gave error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-71-894dc447893f>", line 1, in <module>
    classgraph,texts = plt.bar(dataframe_plot["Percentage"],height=5)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I read quite some posts on how to do this but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You can just *100 for each of your stack

Comment: @roganjosh the rounding was just for the  post here, I edited and included the real values

Comment: Which libraries are you using to handle dataframe and plotting? Adding their tag may be useful.

Comment: it is a pandas dataframe

Comment: I will include the code I've tried

Comment: @roganjosh you are right, I should have included it right away, but I made the edit now.

Comment: df.set_index('Class').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True) by Seaborn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's say you have this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

data = {'Class': ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'],
        'mid-term': [345, 123, 74],
        'final':[235, 345, 632]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()


#    Class  mid-term    final
#0  class1  345       235
#1  class2  123       345
#2  class3  74        632
```

If you plot it, the results will be messy.

```
df.set_index('Class').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

In order to solve the problem, you need to calculate the percentage for each column. Then plot it.

```
df['mid-per'] = (df['mid-term'] / df['mid-term'].sum() * 100)
df['final-per'] = (df['final'] / df['final'].sum() * 100)

df.set_index('Class')[['mid-per', 'final-per']].T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer. One more question: Where exactly do you use Seaborn?

Comment: @Robvh I'm so sorry for the confusion. It's my habit to set seaborn style. That's why I mention seaborn idly.

Comment: Thanks! The ```T.plot()``` function, what is it exactly? Can't seem to find it on google. I know ```df.plot()``` is a pandas plot. But what is the "T"?

Comment: @Robvh 'T' stands for transpose(). It swaps columns and index. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html

Comment: Thank you, but why is that needed in this example? I indeed receive a dataframe then which is horizontally oriented, but why does the .plot function need it as this input?

Comment: @Robvh That's because you wanted to stack 'percentage' of 'class'. The index is used for X-axis, whereas columns serve as Y-axis


So, if we didn't transpose it, we would get each 'class' as x, and one 'percentage' column as stacks instead. In your case, this would not make any sense since you had only one percentage column.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, very good to know. Thank you for the info!